How can I extract specific data in SQL that are in between """": in column A into column B?
I'm trying to extract every data in my column that are in between "" "": here are sample data:



Column A




{""Activity"":""ConnectFromExternalApplication"",""Id"":""xz[we-654231-aja"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2024-02-13T17:59:44"",""Operation"":""ConnectExternal"",""OrganizationId"":""[REDACTED]"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""bb0-649-429-a53f-b6328"",""Workload"":""BI"",""ResultStatus"":null,""UserId"":""bb0-16-4219-a53f-665328"",""ClientIP"":null,""CustomData"":""""}


{""Id"":""f120-00c3-4ddb-ba60-c9ed83df0"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2023-03-13T17:46:14"",""Operation"":""ViewReport"",""OrganizationId"":""[REDACTED]"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""100300009C22A108"",""Workload"":""PowerBI"",""UserId"":""Ben.@x.uk"",""ClientIP"":""213.174.203.7"",""Activity"":""ViewReport"",""ItemName"":""Opt Dashboard"",""WorkSpaceName"":""UK Operational Reports"",""DatasetName"":""Operational Dashboard"",""ReportName"":""Operational Dashboard"",""CapacityId"":""82EF1AA9-0554-4E95-B249-15F"",""CapacityName"":""BI UK Capacity 1"",""WorkspaceId"":""6588ee54-5b73-441d-a3ac-f133f"",""AppName"":""UK Operational Reports"",""ObjectId"":""Operational Dashboard"",""DatasetId"":""1cd1ce2f-9395-4be0-9521-3e38e7e236b8"",""ReportId"":""76d769fd-a9ec-4c77-ac3d-7cd57d9449ca"",""ArtifactId"":""76d769fd-a9ec-4c77-ac3d-7cd57d9449ca"",""ArtifactName"":""Opt Dashboard"",""IsSuccess"":true,""ReportType"":""PowerBIReport"",""RequestId"":""a2214fde-dffc-7c30-083c-6702b7"",""ActivityId"":""f61bed2a-5906-425c-8048-682a779900aa"",""AppReportId"":""e0ab7628-73b5-4832-9161-c966996d293e"",""DistributionMethod"":""Apps"",""ConsumptionMethod"":""Power BI Web"",""AppId"":""e44d1e27-1d9d-4585-a477-fb66fcd"",""ArtifactKind"":""Report""}



value such as Activity, DatasetId, RecordType anything that are in between "" "": needs to be extracted and place in one column



Column B




Activity, ConnectFromExternalApplication, Id, RecordType, CreationTime, Operation, ..., CustomData


Id, ..., ArtifactKind




Why are all the double-quotes doubled? If this is supposed to be JSON, there should just be a single pair of double-quotes around each string.

E.g. "Activity":"ConnectionFromExternalApplication"

If you format it correctly you'll be able to use the built-in JSON functions.

This are the only data provided to us, so we still don't have idea why double-quotes are doubled

We're using Databricks is it supported in there? At the moment we're sticking on the SQL functionality of the Databricks

You could try using REPLACE(columnA, '""', '"') to undouble them, then use JSON functions on that. E.g. JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(columnA, '""', '"'), "$.Activity")

I don't know Databricks. If it's MySQL, it should be supported.

That's the problem we are dealing with large amount of data not every row has Activity, some data are completely different from other data so specifying every data that are in "":  is not a viable solution, take for example ArtifactKind, or Power BI Web

That's why what I'm trying to extract is anything that are in middle of "":

That's going to be difficult, SQL's string processing functions are very primitive.

If you can do it in the application programming language, you'll be much better off.

Is there a work around here using Python?

Maybe I can use dataframe as an alternative if SQL is not a viable option here

Maybe, but you still need to somehow convert the text to a standard format that can be parsed.

In the 1st sample row there exists 4th element between "" substring which is ""xz[we-654231-aja"". But it is ignored in desired result - why?

Which environment are you on? if it is in ORACLE you can use REPLACE to remove the double quotes and then fetch the data

Please remove this "answer" and write it as a comment.

I'm using Databricks

@NathanaelTomAterado, have you tried something like this SELECT replace(string, what_to_replace, value_to_replace);

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_KEYS(REPLACE(ColumnA, '""', '"')), '[\\[\\]\\" ]', '')
FROM test;




REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_KEYS(REPLACE(ColumnA, '""', '"')), '[\[\]\" ]', '')




Id,UserId,UserKey,Activity,ClientIP,UserType,Workload,Operation,CustomData,RecordType,CreationTime,ResultStatus,OrganizationId


Id,AppId,UserId,AppName,UserKey,Activity,ClientIP,ItemName,ObjectId,ReportId,UserType,Workload,DatasetId,IsSuccess,Operation,RequestId,ActivityId,ArtifactId,CapacityId,RecordType,ReportName,ReportType,AppReportId,DatasetName,WorkspaceId,ArtifactKind,ArtifactName,CapacityName,CreationTime,WorkSpaceName,OrganizationId,ConsumptionMethod,DistributionMethod



fiddle
